# Telerik MVC DateTimePicker not working in a grid

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have been working with the Telerik controls for MVC, and have come accross an issue with the DateTimePicker with their latest release 2011.1.315.

The issue is, when using the datetimepicker in a grid, it does not post back the correct values to the controller.

Having looked at it for a while it seems like it may be a regional setting, I have added date formats to the dateTimepicker and now the date picker works, but the datetimePicker and TimePicker do not. My Regional settings are English UK.

I have also uploaded a [project to the Telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/date-time-picker-does-not-work-in-grid-mvc2-2011-1-315.aspx) forum that highlights this issue.

I would like to remove the "hard coded" date time formats. and get it to post back the correct date time and time values.

If anyone can tell me how to implement this correctly, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known issue, which was fixed after release of Q1 2011. I have answered you in [the forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/date-time-picker-does-not-work-in-grid-mvc2-2011-1-315.aspx). The modified JavaScript file is included in the answer.